# Kotlin extensions does not work with java.util.UUID

Tags: java, function, kotlin, uuid

I've tried to create extension function in Kotlin, however, compilator does not see it, it does not work, no matter if I import it manually or not, other extensions work well in my code.
It event does not work if I put this extension in a class where I want to use it.

```
import java.nio.ByteBuffer
import java.util.*

fun UUID.fromDatabase(byteArray: ByteArray): UUID {
    val bb: ByteBuffer = ByteBuffer.wrap(byteArray)
    val high: Long = bb.getLong()
    val low: Long = bb.getLong()

    return UUID(high, low)
}
```

[image]

EDIT:
I see that is not possible, to add static extension, I had to do something like below:

```
fun KClass<UUID>.fromDatabase(byteArray: ByteArray): UUID {
    val bb: ByteBuffer = ByteBuffer.wrap(byteArray)
    val high: Long = bb.getLong()
    val low: Long = bb.getLong()

    return UUID(high, low)
}
```

and the usage

```
val id = UUID::class.fromDatabase(element["id"] as ByteArray)
```

Comment: https://github.com/Kotlin/KEEP/issues/348

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your extension is on the UUID instance, that's why it's not working when called as a static method (but, for example, `UUID.randomUUID().fromDatabase(...)` would work)

You would be able to do this if UUID class was written in Kotlin and had public companion object, so that your extension function would have been on `UUID.Companion`, but in this case it's impossible.

Comment: Yes, I've already discovered that (in edit section), maybe it will be an option in the future: https://github.com/Kotlin/KEEP/issues/348

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to create an extension function on the class UUID, but you use it as a static method. Extension functions in Kotlin are not static methods, they are instance methods. So, you cannot call them on the class itself, you can only call them on an instance of the class.

In your case, you can create a top-level function instead of an extension function. Here is how you can do it:

```
import java.nio.ByteBuffer
import java.util.*

fun fromDatabase(byteArray: ByteArray): UUID {
    val bb: ByteBuffer = ByteBuffer.wrap(byteArray)
    val high: Long = bb.getLong()
    val low: Long = bb.getLong()

    return UUID(high, low)
}
```

And you can use it like this:

```
val id = fromDatabase(element["id"] as ByteArray)
```